# removing glue from felt pads on chair legs

Tags: adhesive

I am trying to remove old glue from chair felt pads.  I have tried GooGone, sanding and paint thinner.  Does anyone have a remedy for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the glue is still tacky at all (or ever was), Laquer Thinner or "Goof Off" may be a good solvent.  If the glue is a hard type glue such as Elmer's or a Wood glue, your best bet is to try to chip off as much as possible with a sharp pocket knife. Then a block sander or electric sander may work OK for the rest.  Or if you have access to a flat bastard file ($4.99 or so at Sears Hardware or Home Depot, Lowe's, etc..), then you can really put some muscle into it.

Answer (score 1):

I had chairs that had the felt pads on top of chair gliders, bought used. Chairs very hard to move on tile, got stuck, left black gunk on floor.  Used hammer and screw driver, chiseled them off. Worked great. Chairs move wonderfully now.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can get some evo stick adhesive remover...its in a red tin. It really is the best...we use it in the factory so it is industrial strength stuff. If that doesn't get it off I doubt anything will.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently with some old flimsy chairs.

1. Secure chair on the side or upside down, if the legs are flimsy maybe secure them as well.
2. Use a sharp wood chisel to remove the chunks.  Watch your hands, fingers and wear eye protection.
3. Work chisel between the wood and glue or slice through layers of glue.
4. Once the majority is gone, use a sanding block or orbital sander to sand down to the wood.  You want the sandpaper backed by a hard surface.

It sounds like you are almost there, the two main ingredients are determination and patience.

Answer (score -1):

I've always use nail varnish remover and a old rag.